# Converting one color to another based on the relationship of another pair

Tags: c#, colors

Say I have two colors, red and pink. How would I define a relationship between them such that I would be able to use it to get say, light blue from blue? The 'pink' isn't just light red, so I don't want to use `ControlPaint.Light`. The easiest way I can think of is to get the HSB difference between red and pink and just add that to the base blue color, but c# lacks methods to convert those HSB values back to RGB and I would rather not write my own if I can help it. Is there another way?

Comment: If you don't want to write own code, just use [existing code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123998/algorithm-to-switch-between-rgb-and-hsb-color-values)

Comment: @NicoSchertler I would like to use as little non-native code as possible--essentially I'd like to know if there's a way beside the one I posted to do this.

Comment: What's non-native about the code the Nico linked to?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to adjust the lightness of a color without changing the hue, your best option is to convert the RGB color to HSL.  Then adjust the lightness by a certain amount.  Then convert it back to RGB if needed.

You can find a lot of examples of code to use to do the conversion such as the following:

[Convert RGB bytes to HSL and back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847760/convertation-rgb-bytes-to-hsl-and-back)